# java save html page as PDF using FOP and include javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP to create a PDF file that renders an HTML page. This page contains charts generated using a JavaScript library (https://www.shieldui.com). I was able to perform HTML (-> FOP) -> PDF conversion, but the output PDF file does not display any charts, only text.

Am I missing any steps? Is there any way of including JavaScript libraries into FOP XSLT?

Comment: The javascript library create charts as SVG images, and FOP can process SVG images, so I think the problem is in the HTML -> FO conversion; what tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using batik-1.8

Comment: Does the generated FO file contain the svg charts? If yes, then it's a FOP problem and you are probably getting some errors (_which ones?_) while producing the PDF. Otherwise it's a problem of the HTML -> FO conversion and you need to add more details about it (_what is the code / command you are using? do you get any error / warning during its execution?_).